# Tab screens popping up from the bottom

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Does anyone know how to fix tab screens sliding up from the bottom?

Each tab screen is inside its own Stack Navigator:

```
export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeStack
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileStack
        }
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;

                var tabImage = null;

                if (routeName == "Home") {
                    tabImage = require("../../../assets/icons/my-story.png");
                } else if (routeName == "Profile") {
                    tabImage = require("../../../assets/icons/my-plan.png");
                }

                return <Image source={tabImage} style={focused ? null : { opacity: 0.8 }} />;
            }
        }),
        animationEnabled: false
    }
);
```

And the stacks are setup as per according to the React Navigation docs:

```
export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: Home
    }
);
```

The screens are popping up from the bottom after they have been lazy loaded. When they are first loaded they fade in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this problem I fixed it by installing React Native Screens

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens